Path to colcon test output directory in a gtest
Is there a way to specify the path to <workspace>/log/test_<date_time>/ from within a gtest executed with colcon test in order to write files into the same directory where the test output logs will be?
Using a relative path:
FILE* outfile = fopen(<filename>, "w");
fprintf(outfile, <content>);
fclose(outfile);

After running colcon test the output file is in <workspace>/build/<package>/<filename>.

This is not possible in general. The colcon log path can be changed using colcon --log-base foo ..., so trying to locate it relative to the build-base or install-base isn't a good idea. The workspace log directory is more-or-less intended for colcon's logs, not necessarily the logs of the packages within the workspace. That said, stdout and stderr from the build and test processes should be captured there.
A related point is that the buildfarm doesn't use colcon to build or test packages, so there is no log directory (or workspace, for that matter).

I went down a bit of a rabbit hole on this, and the best general solution I can come up with would rely on ament.
If you're adding the test using any of the ament CMake functions (i.e. anything other than add_test()), the AMENT_TEST_RESULTS_DIR should be available. You can create a path off from that (such as ${AMENT_TEST_RESULTS_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/my-extra-test-artifact.txt) and pass that as either a command line argument or an environment variable to your test.
This should save the extra artifacts alongside the junit test result XML under the path specified by --test-result-base.

It's been suggested that I do:
#include <rclcpp/logging.hpp>
...
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
...
    directory = rclcpp::get_logging_directory().string()

and the file lands in ~/.ros/log/ which at least seems much better than the build tree.

This may be more of a hack than an elegant answer, but if you know the package name, you could write to the relative path ../../latest_test/<package>/<filename>.
